# Is it frowned upon to request solutions manuals from the author?

Tags: graduate-school, mathematics, etiquette

Maybe the answer to this is probably as vague as "it depends." I'm a graduate student trying to pick up some extra math skills. I'm reading a couple of texts and attempting the exercises but the difficulty/specificity of some exercises is such that I fear somewhat frequently asking for guidance would be burdensome to whoever I ask for help (peers, professors, my advisor, etc.). My preferred system would be to try my hand at a collection of problems for a few days, and check my thinking against a solutions manual (consulting others if I encounter something I really don't understand).

Some authors encourage instructors to contact them for solutions manuals if they are planning on teaching with their book. As a self-studier, should I generally expect a similar offer extends to me, or would it be frowned upon to ask for a solutions manual?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Instructors are reliant on authors restricting access to solution manuals. Hence, I presume some form of vetting process is in place. You might well satisfy the prerequisites of that vetting process. E.g., if you have a university email address that doesn't look like it is a student address. If you don't, then I suppose "it depends" on whether the author will side-step the vetting process for you. You'll certainly need to convince the author that you aren't a student wanting to cheat.

Comment: In some cases, solution manuals are available only to instructors who use the book in their course.  Unfortunately, in some cases students use solution manuals in such a way that they do not learn how to solve problems themselves.  One may think that 20-year-olds are mature enough to avoid reading an answer prematurely.  But unfortunately, one who thiks that would be wrong in many cases.

Comment: I'm a little surprised that the author would be personally involved here. Most distribution efforts of materials for mass-market books are instead handled by the publisher.

Comment: _In some cases, solution manuals are available only to instructors who use the book in their course._ — Pull the other one.  It's got bells on.

Comment: There's also https://math.stackexchange.com as a resource.

Answer (score 10):

Your request, as a self-studier, to obtain the solutions manual seems perfectly reasonable, and I wouldn't hesitate to make it.

It's true that your request might not be successful, because, as some commenters suggested, the solutions manual may be kept away from students to prevent cheating.  It may be hard for them to verify that you are not a student trying to cheat.

However, I see no harm in asking.

Comment: +1. I would also add that many advanced textbooks do not have solution manuals at all :-(